# Release базы данных с Entity Frameworks model first

Tags: entity-framework

Добрый день. Имеется проект с базой данных созданной через Entity Frameworks model first. Debug версия базы подключается через `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB`. Подскажите пожалуйста на что нужно заменить connection string для релиза проекта. Если оставить такую строку то на другом компьютере база выдаёт ошибку подключения. 
И в каком представлении хранится такая база в папке программы?
Видимо я не очень хорошо понимаю структуру базы данных через создание model first.
Заранее спасибо

Скриншот ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите текс ошибки.

Comment: @sp7 Добавил скриншот ошибки в описание.

Comment: В "службах" инстанс вашего `SQL Server` к которому вы подключаетесь запущен? Покажите еще строки подключения.

Comment: @sp7 По мере изучения ошибки понял что зря использовал базу SQL Express, т.к. для этого на компьютере пользователя придётся устанавливать сервер (предусматривается что база будет работать локально, без подключения к серверу).  Сейчас иду в сторону SQL CE, т.к он позволяет подцепить базу непосредственно к проекту.